# Error with string extraction: unused argument

Tags: r, string

I typed this looking for the word "rogers" in a data frame column. It returned "unused argument" Any ideas? Thank you!

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data4$County1 <- data4 %>%
                       str_extract(County, "^\\D{5}(?= \\D{6})")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piping with `%>%` pushes the preceding object (`data4`) into the first argument of the function following. `str_extract` only takes two arguments, so with this piping it gets three. Furthermore, it is not designed to work with data.frames - you should give it the string directly. That is,

```
data4$County1 <- data4$County1 %>%
                       str_extract("^\\D{5}(?= \\D{6})")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data4 <- data4 %>% mutate(County1 = str_extract(County, "^\\D{5}(?= \\D{6})")
```